# Span as a button Safari issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button, safari

When i use span as a button it works flawlessly on any website except **Safari**.

On **Google Chrome** it appears that way:

[image: display in chrome]

But in **Safari** it appears that way:

[image: display in safari]

This is **HTML** Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p>
<span class='btn btn-primary'>I'm a span, styled like a button</span>
</p>

<p>
<button class='btn btn-primary'>I'm a real button</button>
</p>
```

Due to this issue I can't properly click on the button.
I would be grateful if you could fix it.

Comment: is the css property `cursor: pointer` on `.btn`?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. It appears that on Safari cursor's default isn't pointer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
span {
  cursor: default;
}
```